# Why is there a line length limit in Kate?

Tags: kde, text-editor, kate

In Kate, KDE's text editor, and other editors too I'm sure, sometimes files will not open correctly because of this line length limit. Why is it there? Is it safe to set this to an extreme number or is there a way to get rid of it somehow?

My Kate version:

```
Kate
Version 3.10.5
Using KDE Development Platform 4.10.5
```

Comment: Version of Kate that you're using?

Comment: Edited to include that info.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but once I was opening a file with a single extremely long line, maybe a few megs...with line wrapping, syntax highlighting, etc on, even on a modern desktop with a decent CPU I got very serious performance issues, and typing/scrolling had some serious latency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to do it, is by disabling the auto-wrap by changing the line length limit to zero in Settings --> Configure Kate --> Open/Save.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wonder *why* there is a line length limit set, though.

Comment: What a simple solution to stupid problem. They probably have line limit to prevent editor hang up or running out of memory. Who needst hat in now days computers.

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević ... me. Coding directly in large compund files is no fun... :-/ Merry Christmas :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why? Because most shinny editors can hang-up your computer on documents that doesn't have line-endings.

If you have dynamic line, it can use lots of CPU on certain files with long lines. Color Markup also consumes lots of CPU.

Try to use dump a 100Mb MySql Database, and open it on Kate. It should work. Now remove line endings (for example using sed) and if you try again, your computer probably will hang up.

On KDE 3.5, i was using KWrite/KEdit to open SQL dumps of several Gigabytes without problems. I could, because they don't had either dynamic line adjust nor color markup.